# Create a New Record in a SubForm on button click MS Access 2013 VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a main form called **MForm** on that form I have a subform that is a datasheet called **SForm**.

*What I would like to do:*
On MForm I have a button called cmdNew
when I click that button I would like to create a new record inside subform.

But I am not sure what the VBA would look like in order to make that happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the button all you need to do is this:

```
Me!SForm.SetFocus
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
```